# "gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file" warning

Tags: gnome, log

When running Ubuntu 19.10 on both Wayland and X11 I am still getting this "important" warning in gnome-logs:

> gkr-pam: unable to locate daemon control file

Does anyone know what it means and what might be causing it?

Comment: Have you tried starting with a different Linux kernel? In my case, I had the same problem with the latest Linux kernel with the same message. But a version prior to that booted fine.

Comment: @Tun I'm not OP, but I have gone through several kernels since around the end of 2020 December, when I installed 20.04, and I keep having this warning ever since, regardless of kernel version.

Answer (score 1):

My ubuntu 20.04.2 has the same issue.

My workaround is comment this line at /etc/pam.d/gdm-password:
#auth    optional        pam_gnome_keyring.so

after that open terminal and type gdm3:
sudo systemctl restart gdm3.service

Comment: Is this something that may get restored to its original state after an update? In other words, does one need to do this repeatedly?

Comment: no, it is permanent, but before an ugrade you should use the command: 
apt list --upgradable 
and confirm libpam or gdm do not be updated

Comment: This solution is not acceptable to me as it results in a message that the gdm keyring was not found and I have to input my password by hand after every startup.

Answer (score -1):

At this moment you can suppress this message by doing this:
/etc/pam.d/gdm-password

auth    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so only_if=gdm

only_if=gdm should do the trick ...

but it wouldnt auto unlock gnome-keyring :(

Comment: Please don't add a new answer to address [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184191/gkr-pam-unable-to-locate-daemon-control-file-warning/1442692#comment2260302_1325686). Instead, [edit] your other answer and add that info there. Also make sure to properly format your answer. See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help Thanks!

Comment: ok 
i saw this option a few minutes, thanks